# How to make table combining multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, kableextra

Using the example data below, my goal is to create a table (publication-ready would be great, but fine if not) where I calculate what percent of each group within each column (city, race, and gender) attend, fail, or both.

So what percent of city=6 attend, what percent of city=6 fail, what percent of city=6 both. And then repeat for each group within city, each group within race, and each group within gender, with the end result being each of those as rows in the output table and attend, fail, and both being the 3 columns in the output table.

What I attempted was to calculate percentages for each group within each column separately, and then stack them all using `kableExtra`. The kableExtra attempt was so messy and was so incorrect that I didn't even save it, but this was how I started my calculations:

```
race_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(race) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)

gender_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)

city_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)
```

So if there is some way to take those resulting data frames and stack them on top of each other, that would get close to what I'm hoping for as the end result.

A shortened example of how I hope the final table will be organized:

| Group | Attend | Fail | Both |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Race1 | X% | X% | X% |
| Race2 | X% | X% | X% |
| Male | X% | X% | X% |
| Female | X% | X% | X% |
| City6 | X% | X% | X% |
| City9 | X% | X% | X% |
| City12 | X% | X% | X% |

Data:

```
d<-structure(list(city = structure(c(9, 6, 9, 12, 12, 6, 6, 12, 
12, 6, 6, 9, 12, 12, 6, 6, 9, 6, 9, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 6, 12, 
9, 6, 12, 6), format.stata = "%9.0g"), race = structure(c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(White = 1, 
Black = 2, Hispanic = 3, Other = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), gender = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0), label = "gender of subject", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(female = 0, 
male = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), attend = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    fail = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    both = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want the final product to look like, can't you just rbind() those data frames to append them on top of one another?

Comment: I've not used it before, but this seems at least very close to what the [`table1` package does](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html).

Comment: I've been interested in table1, but the examples I've seen rely on the columns being mutually exclusive categories, which is not the case for me.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
# I'm discarding the haven attributes for now ...
mutate(d, across(c(race, gender), unclass)) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c(city, race, gender)) |>
  summarize(.by = c(name, value), across(c(attend, fail, both), ~ 100 * mean(.x))) |>
  arrange(name, value)
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#   name   value attend  fail  both
#   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 city       6      0  38.5     0
# 2 city       9      0   0       0
# 3 city      12      0  45.5     0
# 4 gender     0      0  18.8     0
# 5 gender     1      0  50       0
# 6 race       2      0  43.8     0
# 7 race       3      0  21.4     0
```

To get the literal output you said with a single `Group` column, we can either `paste` them together and remove the original columns, or we can use `tidyr::unite`:

```r
mutate(d, across(c(race, gender), unclass)) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c(city, race, gender)) |>
  summarize(.by = c(name, value), across(c(attend, fail, both), ~ 100 * mean(.x))) |>
  arrange(name, value) |>
  unite("Group", name, value, sep = "")
# # A tibble: 7 × 4
#   Group   attend  fail  both
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 city6        0  38.5     0
# 2 city9        0   0       0
# 3 city12       0  45.5     0
# 4 gender0      0  18.8     0
# 5 gender1      0  50       0
# 6 race2        0  43.8     0
# 7 race3        0  21.4     0
```

and if you'd prefer to have the actual haven labels instead of `city`, etc, then perhaps this:

```r
d |>
  mutate(
    city = as.character(city),
    across(c(race, gender), ~ as.character(names(attr(.x, "labels"))[ match(.x, attr(.x, "labels")) ]))
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c(city, race, gender)) |>
  summarize(.by = c(name, value), across(c(attend, fail, both), ~ 100 * mean(.x))) |>
  arrange(name, value)
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#   name   value    attend  fail  both
#   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 city   12            0  45.5     0
# 2 city   6             0  38.5     0
# 3 city   9             0   0       0
# 4 gender female        0  18.8     0
# 5 gender male          0  50       0
# 6 race   Black         0  43.8     0
# 7 race   Hispanic      0  21.4     0
```

Comment: Oh this is very nice and simple, thanks. Is there a way to order the resulting tibble rows, at least by the broader city/race/gender categories?

Comment: `dplyr::arrange`?

Answer (score 3):

you can use knitr kable to convert to markdown, and from there to latex or html, depending where you want to publish.

btw you dont have to repeat yourself when using pivot and group_by:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(knitr)

d %>%
  pivot_longer(city:gender) %>% 
  unite(Group,name,value) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100) %>%
  kable() # to markdown table

|Group    | percent_attend| percent_fail| percent_both|
|:--------|--------------:|------------:|------------:|
|city_12  |              0|     45.45455|            0|
|city_6   |              0|     38.46154|            0|
|city_9   |              0|      0.00000|            0|
|gender_0 |              0|     18.75000|            0|
|gender_1 |              0|     50.00000|            0|
|race_2   |              0|     43.75000|            0|
|race_3   |              0|     21.42857|            0|
```

##### EDIT

since you asked for publication ready::

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(sjlabelled)


d %>%
  mutate(
    city = as_character(city),
    race = as_character(race),
    gender = as_character(gender),
    )%>% 
  pivot_longer(city:gender) %>% 
  unite(Group,name,value) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(
    attended = mean(attend) * 100,
    failed = mean(fail) * 100,
    both = mean(both) * 100) %>%
  mutate(Group = sub(".*_","",Group)) %>% 
  kable(digits=2, ) %>%
  add_header_above(c(' ', "Percentage"=3)) %>%
  group_rows("City", 1, 3) %>% 
  group_rows("Gender", 4, 5) %>%
  group_rows("Race", 6, 7) %>% 
  kable_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Warning message:
`city` and `gender` have conflicting value labels.
ℹ Labels for these values will be taken from `city`.
✖ Values: 1

Comment: see the edit, i used the haven labels

Comment: How would I get rid of the NA rows before making the table with kable? In my full data, I have a few instances where race and city and gender are missing.

Comment: @user12256545 that's a great answer. Is that the kable package that makes that beautiful table? Someone else mentioned the table1 package also.

Answer (score 2):

To match your desired table and use the code you already have you would simply need to add column name renames and a `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(haven)

race_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(race) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)

gender_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)

city_percentages <- d %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(
    percent_attend = mean(attend) * 100,
    percent_fail = mean(fail) * 100,
    percent_both = mean(both) * 100)

colnames(city_percentages)[1] <- "Group"
colnames(race_percentages)[1] <- "Group"
colnames(gender_percentages)[1] <- "Group"

percentages <- bind_rows(race_percentages,gender_percentages,city_percentages)
```

Output

```
  Group         percent_attend percent_fail percent_both
  <dbl+lbl>              <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1  2 [Black]                 0         43.8            0
2  3 [Hispanic]              0         21.4            0
3  0 [female]                0         18.8            0
4  1 [White]                 0         50              0
5  6                         0         38.5            0
6  9                         0          0              0
7 12                         0         45.5            0
```

You would need to mutate the `Group` column further to match desired values